# R: Cannot allocate memory greater than x MB

Tags: r, memory

I have a main function in R which calls other files to run my program. I call the main file through a bat file(.exe). When I run it line-by-line it runs without a memory error, but when I call the bat file to run it, it halts and gives me the following error:

Cannot allocate memory greater than 51 MB.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Sounds like you're using 64bit R when you run it line by line and 32bit R in your batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should be using 64bit R, if you can.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes), and this from the [R docs](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html).

Answer (score 2):

Memory limitations in R such as this are a recurring nightmare for a lot of us.

Very often the problem is a limit imposed by your OS limits (which can usually be changed on a Bash or PowerShell command line), architecture **(32 v. 64 bit)**, or the availability of **contiguous** free RAM, irregardless of overall available memory.

It's hard to say why something would not cause a memory issue when run line by line, but would hit the memory limit when run as a .bat.

What version of R are you running? Do you have both installed? Is 32-bit being called by `Rscript` when you run your .bat file whereas you run a 64-bit version line by line? You can check the version of R that's being run with `R.Version()`.

You can test this by running the command `memory.limit()` in both your R IDE/terminal and in your .bat file (be sure to `print` or save the result as an object in your .bat file). You might also do well to try *setting* `memory.limit()` in your .bat file, as it may just have a smaller default, perhaps due to differences in your R Profile that's invoked in your IDE or terminal versus the .bat file.

If architecture **isn't** the cause of your memory error, then you have several more troubleshooting steps to try:

1. Check memory usage in both environments (in R directly and via your .bat process) using this:
   `sort( sapply(ls(),function(x){object.size(get(x))}))`
2. Run the garbage collector explicitly in your scripts, that's the `gc()` command
3. Check all object sizes to make sure there are no unexpected results in your .bat process: `sort( sapply(ls(),function(x){format(object.size(get(x)), units = "Mb")}))`
4. Try memory profiling:

   ```
   Rprof(tf <- "rprof.log", memory.profiling=TRUE)
   Rprof(NULL)
   summaryRprof(tf)
   ```
5. While this is a RAM issue, for good measure you might want to check that the compute power available is both sufficient and not varying between these two ways of running your code: `parallel::detectCores()`
6. Examine your performance with Prof. Hadley Wikham's `lineprof` tool (warning: requires `devtools` and doesn't work on lines of code which call the C programming language)

   **References** While I'm pulling these snippets out of my own code, most of them originally came from other, related StackOverflow posts, such as:

   1. [Reaching memory allocation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419769/reaching-memory-allocation-in-r)
   2. [R Memory Allocation "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 75.1 Mb"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917532/r-memory-allocation-error-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-75-1-mb)
   3. [R memory limit warning vs "unable to allocate..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101045/r-memory-limit-warning-vs-unable-to-allocate)
   4. [How to compute the size of the allocated memory for a general type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717826/how-to-compute-the-size-of-the-allocated-memory-for-a-general-type)
   5. [R : Any other solution to "cannot allocate vector size n mb" in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343299/r-any-other-solution-to-cannot-allocate-vector-size-n-mb-in-r?rq=1)